# Reference Error : Object is not Defined While Accessing a Object with "|" in between Angular (Typescript)

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, angular6

Friends, I am Trying to Access an object out of a nested array, everything seems to be fine but I can't access one variable which includes a **|**

Below i am Showing the JSON Data.

```
  var data = {
isbaggage: "true",
O: {
  "BOM|DEL": {
    uid: "1",
    rph: "1",
    baggageOptions: [
      {
        typ: "XC30",
        desc: "30 kg",
        amt: "11400",
        curr: "INR",
        convamt: "11400"
      },
      {
        typ: "XC05",
        desc: "5 kg",
        amt: "1900",
        curr: "INR",
        convamt: "1900"
      },
      {
        typ: "XC10",
        desc: "10 kg",
        amt: "3800",
        curr: "INR",
        convamt: "3800"
      },
      {
        typ: "XC15",
        desc: "15 kg",
        amt: "5700",
        curr: "INR",
        convamt: "5700"
      }
    ]
  }
}
 };
```

This is the code I am trying to access it with.

```
console.log(data.O.BOM|DEL);
```

This is the link of Sandbox link

[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/1oz5vq16v4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write this way,

```
console.log(data.O['BOM|DEL']);
```